# Missing PID for process inside docker container

Tags: docker

I'm running a simple web application inside a docker container. When I look at the output of netstat, the PID/Program name is blank.

`root@fasf343344423# sudo netstat -tulnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address     State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5697      0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      -

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090      0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      -`

I've seen the PID before on a different setup. So, I want to understand if this is because of a setup issue. Appreciate your help

Comment: Did you check the kernel log (as in https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7276)?

Comment: Thanks. That was a great hint!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this with the following change:

1. Edit `/etc/apparmor.d/docker` file and add the following line

   ```
   ptrace peer=docker-default,
   ```
2. `sudo service apparmor restart`

Answer (score 0):

As in my related question
[Which PID is using a PORT inside a k8s pod without net tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991369/which-pid-is-using-a-port-inside-a-k8s-pod-without-net-tools/64294738#64294738)

The lack of POSIX Capability `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` avoids `netstat` to trace the `inode` to `PID`