# Which PID is using a PORT inside a k8s pod without net tools

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, pid, inode

Sorry about the long question post, but I think it can be useful to others to learn how this works.

## What I know:

On any linux ***host*** (*not using docker container*), I can look at `/proc/net/tcp` to extract information tcp socket related.

So, I can detect the ports in `LISTEN` state with:

```sh
cat /proc/net/tcp | 
 grep " 0A " | 
  sed 's/^[^:]*: \(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\):\(....\).*/echo $((0x\4)).$((0x\3)).$((0x\2)).$((0x\1)):$((0x\5))/g' | 
   bash
```

Results:

```
0.0.0.0:111
10.174.109.1:53
127.0.0.53:53
0.0.0.0:22
127.0.0.1:631
0.0.0.0:8000
```

`/proc/net/tcp` gives `UID`, `GID`, unfortunately does not provides the `PID`. But returns the `inode`. That I can use to discover the `PID` using it as file descriptor.

So one way is to search `/proc` looking for the `inode` socket. It's slow, but works on host:

```sh
cat /proc/net/tcp |
 grep " 0A " |
  sed 's/^[^:]*: \(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\):\(....\).\{72\}\([^ ]*\).*/echo $((0x\4)).$((0x\3)).$((0x\2)).$((0x\1)):$((0x\5))\\\t$(find \/proc\/ -type d -name fd 2>\/dev\/null \| while read f\; do ls -l $f 2>\/dev\/null \| grep -q \6 \&\& echo $f; done)/g' |
   bash
```

output:

```
0.0.0.0:111     /proc/1/task/1/fd /proc/1/fd /proc/924/task/924/fd /proc/924/fd
10.174.109.1:53 /proc/23189/task/23189/fd /proc/23189/fd
127.0.0.53:53   /proc/923/task/923/fd /proc/923/fd
0.0.0.0:22      /proc/1194/task/1194/fd /proc/1194/fd
127.0.0.1:631   /proc/13921/task/13921/fd /proc/13921/fd
0.0.0.0:8000    /proc/23122/task/23122/fd /proc/23122/fd
```

### Permission tip 1: You will only see what you have permission to look at.

### Permission tip 2: fake **`root`** used in containers does not have access to all file descriptors in `/proc/*/fd`. You need to query it for each user.

If you run as normal user the results are:

```
0.0.0.0:111
10.174.109.1:53
127.0.0.53:53
0.0.0.0:22
127.0.0.1:631
0.0.0.0:8000    /proc/23122/task/23122/fd /proc/23122/fd
```

Using `unshare` to isolate environment it works as expected:

```sh
$ unshare -r --fork --pid unshare -r --fork --pid --mount-proc -n bash
# ps -fe
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  2 07:19 pts/6    00:00:00 bash
root       100     1  0 07:19 pts/6    00:00:00 ps -fe
# netstat -ntpl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
# python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
[1] 152
# Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
netstat -ntpl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      152/python          
# cat /proc/net/tcp |
>  grep " 0A " |
>   sed 's/^[^:]*: \(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\):\(....\).\{72\}\([^ ]*\).*/echo $((0x\4)).$((0x\3)).$((0x\2)).$((0x\1)):$((0x\5))\\\t$(find \/proc\/ -type d -name fd 2>\/dev\/null \| while read f\; do ls -l $f 2>\/dev\/null \| grep -q \6 \&\& echo $f; done)/g' |
>    bash
0.0.0.0:8000    /proc/152/task/152/fd /proc/152/fd
# ls -l /proc/152/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 mai 25 07:20 0 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 mai 25 07:20 1 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 mai 25 07:20 2 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 mai 25 07:20 3 -> 'socket:[52409024]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 mai 25 07:20 7 -> /dev/urandom
# cat /proc/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 00000000:1F40 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 52409024 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0
```

Inside a docker container in my host, it seems to work in same way.

## The problem:

I have a container inside a kubernetes pod running jitsi. Inside this container, I am unable to get the PID of the service listening the ports.

Nor after installing netstat:

```sh
root@jitsi-586cb55594-kfz6m:/# netstat -ntpl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5269            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5280            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5347            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5222                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5269                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5280                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

```sh
# ps -fe
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 May22 ?        00:00:00 s6-svscan -t0 /var/run/s6/services
root        32     1  0 May22 ?        00:00:00 s6-supervise s6-fdholderd
root       199     1  0 May22 ?        00:00:00 s6-supervise jicofo
jicofo     203   199  0 May22 ?        00:04:17 java -Xmx3072m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -Dnet.java.sip.communicator.SC_HOME_DIR_LOCATION=/ -Dnet.java.sip.communicator.SC_HOME_DIR_NAME=config -Djava
root      5990     0  0 09:48 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
root     10926  5990  0 09:57 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -fe
```

## Finally the Questions:

### a) Why can't I read the file descriptors of the proccess listening port 5222 ?

```
root@jitsi-586cb55594-kfz6m:/# cat /proc/net/tcp | grep " 0A "
    0: 00000000:1466 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   101        0 244887827 1 ffff9bd749145800 100 0 0 10 0                 
...
root@jitsi-586cb55594-kfz6m:/# echo $(( 0x1466 ))
5222
root@jitsi-586cb55594-kfz6m:/# ls -l  /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | grep 244887827                                                     
root@jitsi-586cb55594-kfz6m:/# echo $?
1
root@jitsi-586cb55594-kfz6m:/# su - svc
svc@jitsi-586cb55594-kfz6m:~$ id -u
101
svc@jitsi-586cb55594-kfz6m:~$ ls -l /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | grep 244887827
svc@jitsi-586cb55594-kfz6m:~$ echo $?
1
```

### b) There is another way to list `inode` and link it to a `pid` without searching `/proc/*/fd` ?

### Update 1:

Based on [Anton Kostenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5937420/anton-kostenko) tip, I looked to AppArmor. It's not the case because the server don't use AppArmor, but searching, took me to SELinux.

In a ubuntu machine where AppArmor is running, I got:

```sh
$ sudo apparmor_status  | grep dock                                                                              
   docker-default
```

In the OKE(Oracle Kubernetes Engine, my case) node there is no AppArmor. I got SELinux instead:

```sh
$ man selinuxenabled | grep EXIT -A1
EXIT STATUS
       It exits with status 0 if SELinux is enabled and 1 if it is not enabled.
$ selinuxenabled && echo $?
0
```

Now, I do believe that `SELinux` is blocking the `/proc/*/fd` listing from root inside the container. But I don't know yet how to unlock it.

## References:

https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/10/10/what-even-is-a-container/

Comment: Have you tried `lsof` ?

Comment: (as above) plus .. can/did you try it as user=root? Good question, good luck!

Comment: Philippe, lsof give a lot of entries and `Permission denied`. `lsof | grep -i sock` returns nothing, `lsof | grep -i denied | wc -l` returns `52814`. I'm root inside the pod so I don't understand why I'm unable to list open files started inside de container.

Comment: Did you check an apparmor settings and that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167177/missing-pid-for-process-inside-docker-container) ?

Comment: [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5937420/anton-kostenko), Thanks to pointing the way, now I updated the question, I think it's about `SELinux`, but I can't disable it on this node to test, I will create another cluster where I can.

Comment: this thread looks very interesting. I just curious if you managed to find a solution or tweaks for SELinux.

Comment: Hi Nick, not yet. It's in my `TODO` list, but low priority for now.

Comment: Hi Nick, solved by adding `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` POSIX Capability to the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved by adding the POSIX capability: `CAP_SYS_PTRACE`

I'm my case the container are under kubernetes orchestration.

[this reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) explains about `kubectl` and `POSIX Capabilities`

So I have

```
root@jitsi-55584f98bf-6cwpn:/# cat /proc/1/status | grep Cap
CapInh: 00000000a80425fb
CapPrm: 00000000a80425fb
CapEff: 00000000a80425fb
CapBnd: 00000000a80425fb
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

So I careful read the [POSIX Capabilities Manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). But even adding `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`, the `PID` does not appear on `netstat`. So I tested all capabilities. `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` is ***The Chosen One***

```
root@jitsi-65c6b5d4f7-r546h:/# cat /proc/1/status | grep Cap
CapInh: 00000000a80c25fb
CapPrm: 00000000a80c25fb
CapEff: 00000000a80c25fb
CapBnd: 00000000a80c25fb
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

So here my deployment spec change:

```
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
        ...
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
            - SYS_PTRACE
...
```

Yet I don't know what security reasons `selinux` use to do it. But for now it's good enough for me.

References:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Comment: Note that you should NOT use SYS_PTRACE in **production**, since SYS_PTRACE can be abused to gain root access via privilege escalation as mentioned [here](https://blog.pentesteracademy.com/privilege-escalation-by-abusing-sys-ptrace-linux-capability-f6e6ad2a59cc)